# How many rows & columns do 1,028 equal spaces create...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I have a board that is 17.5" wide and 67" long. I need to divide this board into 1,028 equal spaces. How many rows and how many columns will this equate to?

Comment: We have a few choices. for example we could use one row and $1028$ equally-spaced columns. Other possibilities can be obtained from the prime power factorization $1028=2^2\cdot 257$. Altogether there are $6$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

$1028=257\cdot 2\cdot 2$ and 257 is a prime, so if you want to avoid having any board left over, your choices are restricted to one of
$$ 257\times 4 \qquad 514 \times 2 \qquad 1028 \times 1 $$